# Using FluentMySQL with vapor 3

Tags: mysql, swift, vapor

I have been trying for days to add the fluent-mysql dependancy to my vapor project in order to query my separate mysql database from within the project. However I always seem to get some sort of error e.g. when I try `vapor update` it never completes. (I have left it for hours in the past), I also tried `swift package update` but that had the same error. I am now at the point where `vapor update` works however I am still getting two errors 
        `'mysql/udf_registration_types.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead`

and 
        `Could not build Objective-C module 'CMySQL'`

the only thing I have changed from the vapor web template is `package.swift` which is now this:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "iPadLocator",
    products: [
        .library(name: "App", targets: ["App"]),
        .executable(name: "Run", targets: ["Run"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "2.2.0")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/leaf-provider.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "1.1.0")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-mysql.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "2.0.0"))

    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "App",
            dependencies: ["Vapor", "LeafProvider", "MySQLDriver"],
            exclude: ["Config", "Database", "Public", "Resources"]
        ),
        .target(name: "Run", dependencies: ["App"]),
        .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: ["App", "Testing"])
    ]
)
```

Thanks in advance for any help in advance. This is my first stackOverflow question so sorry if it is awful. I am running `vapor Toolbox 3.1.7` and `Vapor framework 2.4.4`, I have both `mysql` and `cmysql` installed and up to date.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to use Vapor 2 or Vapor 3? (Ignore the version of the toolbox). If you want Vapor 2 then what you have is correct - you just need to change the dependency from `MySQLDriver` to `MySQLProvider`.

If you want Vapor 3 then you need to change all your dependencies to something like

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "TILApp",
    dependencies: [
        //  A server-side Swift web framework.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "3.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-mysql.git", from: "3.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/leaf.git", from: "3.0.0-rc"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "App", dependencies: ["FluentMySQL", "Vapor", "Leaf"]),
        .target(name: "Run", dependencies: ["App"]),
        .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: ["App"]),
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I tried both those and two different yet somehow familiar errors.

Comment: There's another thing to consider for Vapor 2: MySQL 8.x, which is now the default in Homebrew, is incompatible with the current Vapor driver. If you want to go with that route, you **must** downgrade mysql to 5.7.22 and link it. See https://github.com/vapor/documentation/pull/338/files

Comment: Thank you so much. Using mysql 5.7.22 and `MySQLDriver` worked

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting those errors is because Vapor 3 does not contain “Droplet” “Resource”or “ResourceRepresentable” types. Good news is that you successfully installed the vapor 3 dependencies bad news is it looks like in order to use them you will have to make your project vapor 3 ish. Good news, vapor 3 is more performance then Vapor 2.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. How would I go about making my project more vapor 3 ish?

Comment: Vapor 3 is a complete rewrite - you'll need to significantly change your project to adopt it. Have a look at the docs to get started https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/version/upgrading/#24-to-30